# Converting Map<Object, Object> to Object in java giving null

Tags: java, objectmapper

I am using this code

```
final Request arguments = objectMapper.convertValue(event.getArguments(), Request.class);
```

where event look like

```
{
    "arguments": {
      "arePrimary": true,
      "codes": ["ABC"],
      "id": "id",
      "marketplace": "IN"
    },
    "info": {
      "fieldName": "getDetails",
      "parentTypeName": "Query"
    }
  }
```

and the Request looks like

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Request {

    private Boolean arePrimary;

    private String marketplace;

    private String id;

    private List<String> codes;

}
```

But I am getting null when making that conversion, what am I missing here?

Comment: What's the return type of `getArguments()`?

Comment: Map<Object, Object>

Comment: what does the event class look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is from getArguments function as it is returning a null
I have tried the below code and it printed the expected result

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("arePrimary",true);
    map.put("codes",new String[]{"ABC"});
    map.put("id","id");
    map.put("marketplace","IN");
    final Request arguments = objectMapper.convertValue(map, Request.class);
    System.out.println(arguments);
```

result `Request(arePrimary=true, marketplace=IN, id=id, codes=[ABC])`

when calling `objectMapper.convertValue(null, Request.class);` it prints null

Answer (score 1):

Your problem must lie in the actual value returned by getArguments().

Both of these work fine:

```
    @PostMapping("/test")
    public void postTest(@RequestBody Map<Object,Object> event) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<Object, Object> arguments = new HashMap<>();
    
    arguments.put("arePrimary", true);
    arguments.put("codes", new String[] {"ABC"});
    arguments.put("id", "id");
    arguments.put("marketplace", "IN");
    
    final Request arguments2 = objectMapper.convertValue(arguments, Request.class);

    System.out.println(arguments2);

    final Request arguments3 = objectMapper.convertValue(event.get("arguments"), Request.class);
    
    System.out.println(arguments3);
}
```

With POST payload of:

```
{
    "arguments": {
      "arePrimary": true,
      "codes": ["ABC"],
      "id": "id",
      "marketplace": "IN"
    },
    "info": {
      "fieldName": "getDetails",
      "parentTypeName": "Query"
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
Request(arePrimary=true, marketplace=IN, id=id, codes=[ABC])
Request(arePrimary=true, marketplace=IN, id=id, codes=[ABC])
```

Can you put the result of event.getArguments() in a variable and print it.